# React Redux - Methods on store objects

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

One pattern I've seen recommended is to use selectors to where possible to hide the shape of the store. That way if you need to update the shape of the store, you should be able to get away with only updating your selectors, and not other parts of the application.

However the same problem arises with the use of models within the state.

As one of many examples, let's assume I'm building a file system in Redux. I have a list of files which can either be a directory or a file.

My store might have a `fileList` property which contains an array of file ids as well as a `files` object which maps `fileId` to a file object.

Let's say I have a list of files and I want to, depending on whether it's a file or directory, have a different `Item` component (i.e. `DirectoryItem` and `FileItem`).

One way to achieve this is to do something like:

```
{
  files.map(file => {
    file.type = 'directory' ? 
      <DirectoryItem key={file.id} ...file /> : 
      <FileItem key={file.id} ...file />
  )}
}
```

(or I could create a higher-order `FileListItem` component, for example, that does the check and renders either the `DirectoryItem` or `FileItem`)

However this might not be ideal because now my component needs to know the structure of the file object. I might want to add a different type of object (i.e. a shortcut file or shared file) and might decide that a `type` property isn't how I want to represent my data anymore. As such, I'd need to go and update all my components, etc.

If I were doing this in Backbone, for example, I would've probably chosen to define an `isDirectory()` function on my model, however that doesn't seem to be the Redux way of doing things.

One possible solution I can think of is creating a `FileUtils` helper class which exports an `isDirectory` method and takes a file object as a parameter.

Another option will be creating an `isDirectory` selector which takes a file id as a prop, doing something like:

`(files, props) => state.files[props.fileId].type == 'directory'`

If I were to create the selector, I suppose I would need to create a higher-order component to call the selector from.

Just wondering if either approach is recommended in Redux? Am I missing another approach that could help solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functional way of doing things simply prescribes tearing the method off of the object and calling it a function.

The recommended way to call it is to instead of having a `this`, simply pass a regular parameter. This is not a requirement. You can just use `call` or `apply`. That may seem real strange in js, but this may change soon with a new `::` operator.

Now, you can give this function anything you like to help it get its data.

In your example

```
(files, props) => state.files[props.fileId].type == 'directory'
```

You pass it state (naming mistake there) and props and then use this info to come up with an answer. But you could instead choose to pass it a directory entry object. No need to go fetch it from state.

Note that this makes it very close to a method.

```
isDirectory = entry => entry.type === 'dir';
```

Now, because it's not getting state, it isn't selecting anything from state and is therefore not a selector.

However, it's plenty functional in nature. There really is no need or use to make life more complicated than that. Adding a higher order component or trying to shoehorn our problems into a more Redux-y way of doing things is needlessly complicating matters.

Selectors are recommended for selecting state so state usage is not tied to state shape. It's an abstraction layer, separating your `mapStateToProps` from your reducers.

Selectors are now considered part of the Redux Way, but that wasn't always true. And so, at your discretion, being informed of *why* something is done the way it is, you can then choose to *not use it*.

And, at your discretion, you can choose to substitute the current trend with your own version. It is highly recommended to do this, of course after consideration of alternatives.

Often the best solution is the one you come up with yourself. Being the most informed about your problem domain, you are uniquely qualified to formulate a matching solution.

Those who have developed great ideas that all of us feed off of and get inspiration from will probably move on from their viewpoint when something better comes along.

There isn't (and probably shouldn't be) a sacred paradigm. Everything is eligible for reconsideration. Occam's razor dictates that the simplest answer is most likely the right one.

And Redux is very much about simplicity. So to do things the Redux Way is mostly about doing things the straightforward way.